# What do the numbers after an invitee's status in iCal mean?

Tags: icloud, ical, contacts, mobileme

After the text describing the status of an invitee in iCal (in the context menu for the invitee) there is a number. For example I nearly always see numbers like 1.1 or 1.2:

[image]

and occasionally I see "n/a":

[image]

More importantly, I've recently discovered that [one of my invitees is consistently not getting my invitations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34082/4395), and his status (uniquely among all my contacts) shows a different number, 5.1:

[image]

What do these numbers mean and why does one of them seem to be associated with an inability to receive invitations from me?

I am using OS X 10.7.2, iCal 5.0.1, and iCloud. The invitations in question are all being sent to mac.com or me.com addresses.

Comment: A picture here might help - I have several iCal with appointments and have never seen these numbers. You might need to narrow down the server settings your iCal is using and post them for others to reproduce this if it's a server feeding the numbers and not iCal making them up.

Comment: See pictures in the original question.

Comment: No picture in the linked question has any numbers visible and since questions should stand alone, why not link to the image here? In case the other question gets edited, deleted or moved, it's better to have each question stand on it's own. Totally your call though, I tried to reproduce your issue on several macs to no avail, but perhaps someone else will come along with an answer soon.

Comment: @bmike: Ah, sorry, I see what you mean. I was worried doing that to keep the questions distinct. That one is about an issue that may have nothing to do with this one, which is really about what I'm seeing in the UI, independent of whether it's connected to my sending problem.

Comment: @bmike: Also, the sending problem I was having has gone away since the recipient of the un-sendable invitations upgraded his MobileMe; and I no longer see any "5.1"s, so I suspect that the answer to that question is "He's using a very old version of MobileMe" and the answer to  this one is: "The numbers correspond to the recipient's version of MobileMe or iCloud."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These numbers are only present for users who have enabled the iCal "debug menu", using a third party configuration tweaking utility, or the command line

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal IncludeDebugMenu 1
```

which adds them, as part of an additional entry in each invitee's context menu, after his e-mail addresses:

[image]

The numbers themselves contain information about the invitee's version of 
MobileMe or iCloud.